# pip3 on python3.9 fails on 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'

Tags: python, pip, python-3.9

After installing (ubuntu) python3.9, installing some packages with pip failes on:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 24, in <module>
        from setuptools.depends import Require
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/depends.py", line 7, in <module>
        from .py33compat import Bytecode
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/py33compat.py", line 54, in <module>
        unescape = getattr(html, 'unescape', html_parser.HTMLParser().unescape)
    AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera-dl/issues/778 
https://github.com/coursera-dl/edx-dl/commit/5490a99a98b56f544661c131229ef640ace2b064
may help

Comment: I encounter similar issue while using pycharm to create a new venv.  Switch to using powershell fixed my issue.

Comment: If I have to guess, it is not the shell but the python version, you use a different python or different environment (pip etc.) now that you switched.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

After some trial and error I upgraded, pip, distlib and setuptools and it solved it. Not sure which of those is causing it. (On the last two I found issues [1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40093) [2](https://bugs.python.org/issue19688) of other sites)
It is caused by removing unescape from HTMLParser in python3.9, which seems to break setuptools.

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

If it does not work, try also:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade distlib
```

Note from @seb comment: The default pip3 may not be the python you are using. If so, try pip of your specific version used (e.g. pip3.9)

Comment: works for me! Either distlib or setuptools did it for me.

Comment: I tried this, I am using Pycharm IDE but still this is raising an error. I have updated pycharm , setuptools and distlib. What do I do now?

Comment: Try running from the shell, is it possible you run from the wrong environment in pycharm? So it is not really updated?

Comment: pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade distlib
Works for me!!!!

Comment: pip3 install was using default python3 for me (python3.6), so it didn't solve the issue for python3.9. This is what worked: 
python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: This does not fix the error.

Comment: This solution should work up to version 3.9. But from version 3.10 it doesn't work anymore. In this case, just import the `html` package and simply do `html.unescape`.