# Coursera-dl not downloading classes command prompt Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd, coursera-api

I have been trying to install some lectures from coursera using the coursera-dl command, installed via :

```
pip install coursera-dl
```

I also did the coursera-dl.conf file, which includes my username, password, download preferences and cauth from Coursera.org.
I made sure to be logged in on coursera (in ALL of my browsers!!!)
I carefully write the classe's name, i.e. what follows learn/ in the url.
But I encountered errors. I decided to downgrade Python from 3.9.5 to 3.8. I also changed path, in environment variables of advanced settings (control panel) to where the coursera-dl.exe file is.
In addition, I have created the folder for the downloads, have the .conf file in there, and am doing the commands there (it managed to create a coursera-dl folder too, after I git cloned I think).

Anyway, I now get the error below after doing this command:

```
coursera-dl classical-composition
```

Can anyone help me please? Thank you

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\leo\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
        return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
      File "c:\users\leo\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:\Users\Leo\Anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\Scripts\coursera-dl.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
      File "c:\users\leo\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\coursera\coursera_dl.py", line 61, in <module>
        from .cookies import (
      File "c:\users\leo\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\coursera\cookies.py", line 9, in <module>
        import ssl
      File "c:\users\leo\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
        import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Do not prepend the question title with "SOLVED" when a solution is found, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the applicable answer instead…

Comment: @aschipfl sorry about that! new here! Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this works**: Make sure to install Coursera Authentication helper for Firefox and add this to your CAUTH (I noticed this sequence changes everyday and has to be updated in the coursera-dl.conf), login Coursera and you should be ready to download all the classes you wish! *Make sure to go to the classe's link when part of a specialisation*.

If you need more help, you can read my journey **below:**

**EDIT**

This has worked for many classes so far and I am not getting any errors. Using Anaconda 3 command promt. Here is what I did:

In environment variables, I added new paths, stated from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54897379/16367595

```
 D:\Anaconda3 
D:\Anaconda3\Scripts
D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```

Make sure to check what yours looks like, mine was in the C: drive, for instance.

Then I reinstalled:

```
python -m pip install coursera-dl
```

**AND INTERESTINGLY** this has actually only worked for 1 course, i.e. learn to write for screenplay etc initially. I then tried it again when I was getting the error below for another class, and it worked.

```
AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'
```

The following day, I was getting this error for other classes:

```
403 client error, Forbidden for URL
```

So finally, I made sure I was logged in in all of my browsers (not sure if this contributed) however, I think the solution to the above error comes from updating the CAUTH section of the coursera-dl.conf file. The successful cases above worked with the Google Chrome CAUTH cookies from coursera.org. The following day worked when I installed the Coursera Authentication extension [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/coursera-authentication-helper/) and replaced the older CAUTH with the one provided with the extension.

This is working well while using anaconda3 prompt, getting all desired classes downloaded.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it partially working. Now, just sounds like you just need to try updates, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65640476/pip3-on-python3-9-fails-on-htmlparser-object-has-no-attribute-unescape

Comment: Hey thank you for the comment! I have actually been trying those updates, but no luck so far, will see if a restart of the PC helps (although not feeling very optimistic about that one) UPDATE: i have reinstalled with the commands above, and it worked!!!?? I may have to do this before each install?!