# pip installation error downloading all package versions

Tags: python

```
merlins@jimmmmy ~$ pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.13.0)
Collecting absl-py
  Using cached absl_py-0.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (132 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/47/835652c7e19530973c73c65e652fc53bd05725d5a7cf9bb8706777869c1e/absl_py-0.13.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=62bd4e248ddb19d81aec8f9446b407ff37c8175c2ba88266a7afa9b4ce4a333b (from https://pypi.org/simple/absl-py/). Requested absl-py from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/47/835652c7e19530973c73c65e652fc53bd05725d5a7cf9bb8706777869c1e/absl_py-0.13.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=62bd4e248ddb19d81aec8f9446b407ff37c8175c2ba88266a7afa9b4ce4a333b has different version in metadata: '0.13.0'
  Downloading absl-py-0.13.0.tar.gz (114 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 114 kB 1.1 MB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zonnvrc9/absl-py_b3a192de46424d63a91fdfb80e09eae8/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zonnvrc9/absl-py_b3a192de46424d63a91fdfb80e09eae8/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6vtwjr0t
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-zonnvrc9/absl-py_b3a192de46424d63a91fdfb80e09eae8/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/merlins/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
      File "/home/merlins/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 34, in <module>
        from setuptools.depends import Require
      File "/home/merlins/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/depends.py", line 7, in <module>
        from .py33compat import Bytecode
      File "/home/merlins/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/py33compat.py", line 55, in <module>
        unescape = getattr(html, 'unescape', html_parser.HTMLParser().unescape)
    AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'
    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please reformat code, I is impossible to analyze it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip3 on python3.9 fails on 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65640476/pip3-on-python3-9-fails-on-htmlparser-object-has-no-attribute-unescape)

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.